# Can I get the Dragonstone from Bleak Falls Barrow in Skyrim without directly killing the Draugr Overlord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying a Skyrim play style where my character never kills anything directly. The character build is around Stealth/ Illusion and while my character might use Fury to make enemies attack each other the measure is whether the Combat Stats show zero across all kills.

It appears you need to kill the Draugr Overlord in Bleak Falls Barrow to get the Dragonstone which unlocks the dragon spawning.

Apparently [it's possible to progress to Alduin's Wall without any direct kills](http://kotaku.com/5867385/hes-level-35-in-skyrim-he-makes-villagers-kill-his-dragons) - but I'm scratching my head about Bleak Falls Barrow.

My only thought so far is to get a follower and then have them kill the Draugr Overlord, but this doesn't seem quite true to the character I'm trying to play.

If anyone's interested my plan/ (personal challenge) challenge is to collect all of the [Stones of Barenziah](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Stones_of_Barenziah) without directly killing a soul. I'm pretty sure I don't need the dragons active for this, but it doesn't feel like Skyrim without dragons.

Any suggestions for getting the Dragonstone from Bleak Falls Barrow without directly killing the Draugr Overlord?

Comment: You answered the question yourself, but you're not satisfied. What criteria are you looking for?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - I'm not sure if I have. Do follower kills show in the combat stats?

Comment: Get him to follow you up the stairs near his coffin, and then shield-bash him over the edge for some falling damage. Repeat... a lot.

Comment: How did you avoid the huge ass spider?

Comment: @Wouter - ran around it healing myself with magic. The thief got free of the spiderweb and ran into the catacombs, but I can't remember how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a swinging blades trap at the beginning of the Sanctum, perhaps you could drag him back to that?

Comment: That's painful obvious now I read it. Leading enemies into traps should be a major strategy for my character.

Answer (score 0):

There are some traps in the other dungeons that you can lead the Draugr. Followers can work too.